# Problem in using RequiredFieldValidator for validating FCKEditor

Tags: asp.net, validation, fckeditor, requiredfieldvalidator

When i use RequiredFieldValidator for Validation FCKEditor , The first time that the form gonna submit , RequiredFieldValidator prompt (ErrorMessage) and  indicate that FCKEditor is empty , while it isn't . Again  if you try to submit the form  , It's OK and there is no problem .At this case user have to hit the submit button twice

So i have to disable Client Side validation and validate form just  in Server Side code which is not good . Any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the RequiredFieldValidator isn't working for you then I suggest writing a little javascript to do the client-side validation. jQuery does this extremely well. There is a popular plugin that makes it a breeze: [jQuery Validation plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/validate)